# Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1040KB at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)

Tags: java, json, iterator, stringbuilder

I am trying to build query dynamically from json object using `StringBuilder` and `Iterator`.

**method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JSONArray jsonArray = array of json
        
        //for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            //JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.get(i);
            //for sample json
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject("{\"SchemaId\":\"186f134a-e65c-4e2d-92c6-04afe6951dd6\",\"SchemaName\":\"CIR\",\"Schema\":\"{}\",\"Parent\":null,\"Application\":\"CA\",\"ModifiedDateTime\":\"2020-08-31T04:21:46.403\",\"Version\":\"3\",\"PageType\":\"Line\",\"favorite\":false,\"CategoryType\":\"bits\",\"IsDeleted\":true}");
            createPreparedStmtQuery(jsonObject,"mytable");
        //}
        
    }
    public static  String createPreparedStmtQuery(JSONObject record,String tableName) throws JSONException {
        record = modifyRecord(record);

        Iterator<String> keys = record.keys();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("insert or replace into ");
        builder.append(tableName);
        builder.append(" (");

        while(keys.hasNext()){
            builder.append(keys.next()).append(",");
        }
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);

        builder.append(") values(");
        keys = record.keys();
        JSArray valuesArray = new JSArray();
        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String key = keys.next();
            if( record.get(key) != null && record.get(key) instanceof String) {
               
            }

            builder.append("?").append(",");

            valuesArray.put(record.get(key));
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);

        builder.append(");");

        JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
        ret.put("query",builder.toString());
        ret.put("values",valuesArray);
        return ret.toString();
    }

    private static JSONObject modifyRecord(JSONObject record) throws JSONException {

        if (record.has("ValidFrom")) {
            record.remove("ValidFrom");
        }
        if (record.has("ValidTo")) {
            record.remove("ValidTo");
        }

        Iterator<String> keys = record.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String key = keys.next();
            if (record.get(key) instanceof JSONObject || record.get(key) instanceof List) {
                record.put(key,((JSObject)record.get(key)).toString());
            }
        }

        return record;
    }
```

**And an Error receiving like this:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1040KB         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
```

Is there any issue in the above methods?How to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: This code is also vulnerable to SQL injection without proper JSON validation.

Comment: @Glains i am very curis to know what change i need to do .please bit more suggest.for more efficient code.

Comment: `AbstractStringBuilder.append()` does not call itself recursively, so it would not be the cause of `StackOverflowError`. The cause is the repeating entries further up the call stack, i.e. further down the stacktrace. Show us more of the stacktrace, and please format it correctly in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to increase the stack size of your JVM. In your case, the size seems to be 1040KB. You can set it to another value (e.g. 48 MB) like this:

```
java -Xss48m
```

For more details and examples see https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes or the official reference https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html

Comment: where to set  `java -Xss48s`...in jdk class path or System properties...i quite not understanding?

Comment: @r08 On the command prompt, right after the `java` command.

Comment: Dependent on how you start your application. Normally you would run from the console this command `java HelloWorld` (where HelloWorld is your class name, it is not included in code sample you provided). Instead you do now `java -Xss48m HelloWorld`. In Eclipse IDE you can set the arguments under "Run" -> "Run configurations" -> "Arguments" -> "VM arguments". Similar in other IDEs.